# Проблема с json_decode

Tags: json, php, javascript

На клиентской стороне имеем функцию посылающюю post запрос содержащий json данные:

```
function sendRequest(data, target, callback){
    target=target || '#main';
    callback=callback || function(){};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./private/hub.php",
        data: "r="+JSON.stringify(data),
        success:callback
    }).done(function( answer ){$(target).html(answer);});
}
```

На сервере запрос обрабатывается так

```
$r=$_POST['r']; 
$request=json_decode(stripslashes($r));
```

Все отлично работает на Apache под виндой, но под линуксом json_decode() возвращает null в том случае если json  содержит экранирующие символы. Магические кавычки и в лине и винде включены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта функция возвращает null, если json не может быть распарсен или его глубина превышает предел рекурсии для PHP.

```
json_last_error Можно узнать что именно не так:
```

[вот ссылка](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: О спасибо ответ - неправильно оформленный синтаксис json, но как так если в винде все прекрасно работает. Запрос кстати содержит только экранированные двойные кавычки.

Comment: Ну значит **"Syntax error"** значит запрос неправильный и что-то у тебя с кавычками :)

Comment: Спасибо кэп)) Ладно кавычки, загадочный смысл фразы Syntax error мне было не под силу понять)) Ну а если по существу, что-то я не пойму что мне делать. Может выпить пива?!

Comment: Пива можно.
Можешь скинуть весь код, файл который отправляет данные и сам php скрипт. на почту или куда-нить.

Comment: Да нет спасибо, я уже решил проблему. Оказывается проблема лежала в другом месте: я делал двухуровневый json и по тупости, когда копипастил не убрал JSON.stringify(). Отсюда и множественные экранирования всех кавычек. Правда не понятно почему все отлично работало под виндой, видимо где-то все-таки есть небольшая разница в реализациях php. Всем еще раз огромное спасибо узнал много нового!

Comment: Дяди Билли, иногда делает чудеса :)

Answer (score 1):

1. data: "r="+JSON.stringify(data), заменить на "r=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))
2. > > Магические кавычки и в лине и винде включены.

а если найду ? (с). По теме - не верю что они выключены.

1. Если они выключены, то stripslashes в $request=json_decode(stripslashes($r)); лишний.

Comment: **включены**

Comment: да, спасибо, чет я слепой уже...

Comment: Не сработало(

Comment: перед json_decode(stripslashes($r)) сделайте var_dump(stripslashes($r))

что выведет под виндой и под линукс ?

Comment: Сделал теперь вижу что под линем все внешние и внутренние кавычки двойные, а в винде внешние одинарные. WTF? В голову кроме костыля ничего не лезет.

Comment: Может отключить магические кавычки? :D

Но нет, лучше костыль поверх костыля...

Comment: ахах... ух как мило...

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте `json` [тут](http://json.parser.online.fr/).